# Joomla: display page heading of menu item

Tags: php, joomla

I want to display the page heading of a Joomla menu item if this is filled. I've tryed with this code wothout success:

```
<h1 class="title">
    <?php
        if (null === ($this->params->get('page_heading')))
        {
            $mydoc = JFactory::getDocument();
            $mytitle = $mydoc->getTitle();
            echo $mytitle;
        }
        else 
        {
            $active = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
            echo $active->params->get('page_heading');
        }
    ?>
</h1>
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved myself this way:

```
<h1 class="title">
    <?php $menu  = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
        $active = $menu->getActive();
        $mydoc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $mytitle = $mydoc->getTitle();
        $pageHeading = $active->params->get('page_heading');
        if($pageHeading != "")
        {
            echo $pageHeading;
        }
        else 
        {
            echo $mytitle;
        }
    ?>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar need and noticed this code doesn't work in Joomla 4.
Here is my solution:

### Joomla 3

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
$title = $menu->title;
$page_heading = $menu->params->get('page_heading');
echo $page_heading ?? $title;
```

### Joomla 4

```
$menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu()->getActive();
$title = $menu->title;
$page_heading = $menu->getParams()->get('page_heading');
echo $page_heading ?? $title;
```

The only difference between these 2 is how you get the menu item params, `params` in J3 vs `getParams()` in J4.